# Is it legal for using the limited free storage of Google Drive freely for business? Or should one buy a license for it?

Tags: internet, google

A space of 15 GB is given free by Google Drive.

Is this only for personal use or can I use this freely for business?

Answer (score 2):

[Previously](https://www.google.com/drive/terms-of-service/archived/), this was prohibited under the Google Drive TOS, when there was a separate TOS for Google Drive. They [then subsumed](https://policies.google.com/terms/changes?hl=en-US) Chrome, Chrome OS and Drive under the unified Google TOS, so the current agreement for Drive is composed of the [pan-Google terms](https://policies.google.com/terms) plus the [Google Drive Additional Terms](https://www.google.com/drive/terms-of-service/). Neither the core terms nor the additional terms (current versions) restrict one to non-commercial usage.

Answer (score 0):

The Google terms and conditions cover how a business can make and operate an account. Nothing states the business can't use a free account, besides the practical issues that may arise from only having 15gb.

Comment: A link to the terms would be helpful

Comment: @DaleM If only there were some way to search the internet for Google's terms...

Comment: Ha Ha. While it should be possible to find the relevant terms with an online search (indeed a google search) a GOOD stack exchange answer would include such a link as a supporting source, in my view.

Comment: My internet connection doesn't have a license for commercial use, only private use. I use it to work from home; clearly commercial. I enquired, and basically it means that if anything goes wrong, I'll be treated like a private customer; I can't get more in damages than my money back, and I'll be last in the list to fix problems. I commercial license costs three times as much with no advantage as long as the line works, but much better service in case of problems.